# Token Login Between C++ and C#?

Tags: c#, c++, mysql, asp.net

Here is what I am trying to do. I have an asp .net website in C#. I also have a game server and game both written in C++. The game server is hosted where the web site is.

What I want is for users to be able to automatically login to the website when they click a button in the game. That is, the game makes a request to the game server, and some how a token is generated that can be used to log into the website.

So the server might sendback something like:

```
www.contoso.com/tokenlogin?userid=67456353&token=576434324431fgdsastr
```

I'm aware that an easy solution to this is to just create a token in the database that the web site can read. If I cannot find a better solution, I'll do that, but ideally I would like to generate a token whereby for the next 5 minutes, passing this token with this userid will login that user as if they had passed their password.

A simple idea I had for this was to hash their password hash and username which would work, but this does not have a timestamp.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this? Can MySQL generate tokens that can be validated? I'm using MySQL. I don't mind a solution that uses the database, I just don't want a solution that writes to the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a random token and saving it to the database (with a timestamp) is definitely the easiest solution.  Failing that (or another way of communicating between processes), what you can do is generate signed tokens in your server which can be validated by your web app.  So your server would create a token like:

```
{userid: XXX, issueTime: YYY}
```

Then, you encrypt this data with an authenticated encryption method like GCM, base-64 encode it, and append it to the URL.  Your web app decrypts and validates the data, and if the timestamp is ok logs the user in.  This requires a shared key between the processes, which you must not lose.

Comment: Can MySQL encrypt and decrypt data given a key?

Comment: Cool; they have an Encrypt function :)

Comment: My understanding is that MySql `encrypt` just calls `crypt` on the system, which is considered obsolete on *nix.

Comment: I'm using aes encrypt which is doing great :)